# Line and Column number of properties while parsing YAML using SnakeYML (Scala)

Tags: scala, yaml, snakeyaml

I want to find out the line and column number of each property in the YAML/YML file in Scala. I'm using SnakeYML for a lack of better alternative, though I'm open to suggestions.

I've tried to load YAML through the `YAML()` constructor but it keeps failing. After going through the docs, there is a `Node` type where this information is stored but cannot get my YAML as an instance of that type.

This is an example YML file. It could be unstructred. Thanks in advance.

```
data_source_id: scheduled_query
schedule: 
  - hello: world
query: |
  select
      abc,
      def,
      ghi,
      count(abc) as abc_count
    from `users`
    group by 1,2,3,4
```

Comment: What error do you get? What code did you try? In the endw what result do you expect?